# Google maps disapears after replacing wp_head() with same code output from source code

Tags: wordpress, seo

So im optimizing a website to make page load faster, and editing some of the script includes in the header. What im trying to do, and its working weird for some reason, is looking up in the browser source code what the wp_head() function outputs, and copying and pasting it identical to the html file editor, so i can add async to the script tags, and do a couple of other things

Its working fine, except for some reason, google maps isnt showing up. Which doenst make sense because the final code is supposably identical. The only difference is that when it works, im using wp_head(), and when it doesnt, im hardcoding the exact output from wp_head, and removing that function

Any idea why that is?

Heres the site

http://tinyurl.com/mcquxmu

the blank area is the google maps, and im not seeing any errors in the console... nothing else on the page has been edited. Only the content from wp_head which i place in between comments.

Comment: I would not remove the wp_head function. Could have many unintended consequences, as plugins or your theme may hook functions into it. - Are you using any plugin to display the map ?

Comment: yeah, its using  a plugin.... it just doesnt make sense tho, the final source code in the browser looks identical weather i leave wp_head there or not.... i dont understand why its not working.

Comment: how else could i go about adding asyng to the script includes? where is wp_head being generated? thanks for your help

Comment: The scripts in wp_head are often found inside functions.php (depending on who built the theme) - Your map plugin is likely trying to hook into the wp_head. Have you turned on your error reporting? define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); function. Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script & https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG